# Combining table information using Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I would like to combine information on two tables in power BI, with a filtering option.

I've tried making a new table merging the two tables together to no avail.

I have one table "Table1" that has multiple types of something, if i filter that table to just one type, I would like to see all the 'cases' associated with that type. 
I am trying to get those associated cases to be the first column of the new table. Then I'd like to use the 'Key' from table1 to get an associated 'name' to use as the header row.
Then I'd like to fill the table with the 'values' of table 1.

That sounds very confusing and, for me at least, it is. I have a diagram to try and help describe my situation.

[image: Example]

Any help would be awesome! I can not figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Edit Queries > Merge Queries > Merge Queries As New` and merge the two tables:

[image]

Then expand the table. It should look like this:

[image]

Now select the column `Name` and go to `Transform > Pivot Column`.
As column Values use `Value` and select the option `Dont Aggregate`.

[image]

As next step go to `Home > Group By`:

[image]

Close and apply. Put a table into your report and a filter and check the reults:

Even:

[image]

Odd:

[image]